# Change Logfile Name every 15 minutes without overwrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to write my program output to a log file whose name should change every 15 minutes and 
currently I am doing this way.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1TempLog1_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"

today0915 = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=15, second=0,microsecond=0)
today0930 = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=30, second=0,microsecond=0)
today0945 = datetime.now().replace(hour=9, minute=45, second=0,microsecond=0)
today1000 = datetime.now().replace(hour=10, minute=0, second=0,microsecond=0)
today1015 = datetime.now().replace(hour=10, minute=15, second=0,microsecond=0)

while <my condition>:

    if datetime.now() > today0915 and datetime.now() <= today0930:
        FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log1_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"
    if datetime.now() > today0930 and datetime.now() <= today0945:
        FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log2_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"
    if datetime.now() > today0945 and datetime.now() <= today1000:
        FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log3_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"
    if datetime.now() > today0945 and datetime.now() <= today1000:
        FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log4_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"
    if datetime.now() > today1000 and datetime.now() <= today1015:
        FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log5_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"

    print("Time", datetime.now(), "FileName:", FullLog)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Is there any dynamic way to do this procedure.

Comment: Maybe you should use the `logging` package and the [right handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During while loop, get the current time. Then figure out how many minutes does it have. For ex., 10:20 has 20 minutes. Now divide it by 15 and add 1 to get the file name.

```
now = datetime.today().minute
log_seq = num//15 + 1 #just check edge cases around 60 and 00 .. // for python3
FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log"+log_seq+"_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"
```

Comment: Note that the question is about Python 3, so `num/15` will produce a float.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did notice the python3 thing but didn't expect that basic functions such as numerical operators have been modified in p3.

Comment: But how to handle edge cases around 60 and 00 ?. Continuous numbering of log file name will also work for me.

Comment: That is something you need to figure out. Do you want 00 to be logfile 4 or 1. Things like that can be checked via if/else

Comment: I want the Log Seq number to continue like logfile4.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have done like: FullLog = datetime.today().strftime("Prog1Log"+ str(hour) + str(log_seq) +"_%d_%m_%Y") + ".txt"